# How to send POST for both master and detail tables?

Tags: json, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Currently I am using the following post method and it is return error 500 internal server error. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    at WebApi.Controllers.OrderController.PostOrder(Order order)

```
        public async Task<ActionResult<Order>> PostOrder(Order order)
        {
            
            // order table
            _context.OrderRequests.Add(order);
            
            // orderitem table
            foreach (var item in order.OrderItems)
            {
                _context.OrderItems.Add(item);
            }
            
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetOrder", new { id = order.OrderID}, order);
            
         }
```

What is wrong? How do I submit POST on both tables? Or do I have to create a separate web api controller for OrderItems?

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at WebApi.Controllers.OrderController.PostOrder(Order order) in C:\dev\Test\WebApi\Controllers\OrderController.cs:line 91
at lambda_method(Closure , Object )
at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable.Awaiter.GetResult()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Comment: You need not create a separate API controller for nested items. I tried to replicate the scenario with a nested structure like yours (Parent class having a List<Child> classes as one of its members) and could post the data successfully. Model binding does not seem to have any issue. `500`  could be because of a server side issue. Looking at the stacktrace of the exception could provide more information.

Comment: I added the whole exception details. I am using angular for front end. Do you think the problem would be there? Or at the asp.net core web api?

Answer (score 1):

Just save your changes to the context before adding "child" records:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult<Order>> PostOrder(Order order)
    {
        
        // order table
        _context.OrderRequests.Add(order);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        
        // orderitem table
        foreach (var item in order.OrderItems)
        {
            _context.OrderItems.Add(item);
        }
        
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction("GetOrder", new { id = order.OrderID}, order);
        
     }
```

Comment: nice it worked, but now i am able to update the order table, but the order details table is not updated, and it still returns the same error 500 as above. do i have to use a dto to hide the foreign keys?

Comment: "but the order details table is not updated" - what does it mean?

Comment: ok so the json for the order is {"OrderID":9,"OrderNo":"358602","CreatedOn":"2020-08-12","UserID":4,"User":null,"OrderItems":null}. And after POST, the Order table is updated with the values OrderID: 9, OrderNo: "258602", CreatedOn: "2020-08-12", UserID: 4. But the OrderItems Table is not filled up with the selected items.

Comment: Oh I found a typo in the models... So now the OrderItems table is updated as well. But somehow there is still an error 500. Why is that so? Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
 ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'OrderItems' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.